# How to add multiple name using append in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a name as using jQuery append() Method. I expect the output as
1.kuldeep
2.parth
3.Akruit
4.hement... etc
[image]

I expect the output as 
1.kuldeep
2.parth
3.Akruit
4.hement..ect

Comment: use this `$("ol").append("<li>" + $("#text").val() + "</li>")`

Comment: `$('ol').prepend(\`<li>${text.value}</li>\`)`.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are appending the values wrong you should be doing it as below

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
     $("ol").append("<li>"+$("#text").val()+"</li>");
});
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to remove in this list to add? for example I have entered name kuldeep and click on the add button it will be add on list ok. But how to remove the name in a list using remove method?

Comment: @KuldeepPatel its definitely off-topic to answer it here please do post a new question removing an element  refer this before adding a new question : https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_remove.asp